# Vue 3 composition api - computed is returning undefined

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

```
//hook.ts
export const useCreatePassVm = () => {
    const state = reactive({
        password: '',
        repeatPass: ''
    })

    const isMatchi = computed(() => state.password.length > 0 )

    return { isMatchi }
}
```

**isMatchi** must return boolean, but is **undefined**

```
my sfc vue file

<template>
<UiText v-if="!vm.isMatch">not match</UiText>
</template>
<script setup lang="ts">

import { useCreatePassVm } from './hooks'

const vm = useCreatePassVm()

</script>
```

and if i rewrite, for example

`const isMatchi = computed(() => state.password )`

**also** undefined

in vue component `const isMatchi = computed(() => state.password.length > 0 )` must return boolean

Comment: Wanted to call the function `isMatch`, but declared `isMatchi`... the letter `i` is very confusing at the end

Answer (score 0):

Your code works

```js
const { createApp, reactive, computed } = Vue;

const useCreatePassVm = () => {
    const state = reactive({
        password: '',
        repeatPass: ''
    })
    const isMatchi = computed(() => state.password.length > 0 )
    return { isMatchi }
}

const App = { 
  setup() {
  const vm = useCreatePassVm()
  return { vm }   
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
isMatchi : {{ vm.isMatchi }}
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, however i said that he wanted to call the function `isMatch` instead of `isMatchi`. Thats not really problem, just corrupted word...